# How do you extract confidence intervals and OR out of the step() function in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stepwise-regression

I've been wondering something for a while. If you run a simple regression model in R and then perform a step-wise selection (it doesn't have to be the way I typed the code below), how do you extract some of the "relevant" information of the model in R suchs as Odds Ratios and/or confidence intervals?

The general model would look the following:

```
glm<-glm(y~x+z+n+p, family=binomial(link="logit))
step(glm, direction="backward", test="F")
```

Interestingly, in the newest version of R, I can't save an object as the step function.

```
stepmodel<-step(glm, direction...)
```

Only runs the stepwise selection model. 
So performing `step$anova`or `conf(step)`- or even better `exp(conf(step))`etc. doesn't seem possible....

Any ideas on this? Also, would any of you know of a package, where a stepwise variable selection of a cox-regression model is possible?

Thanks a mill for your thoughts and help.

Cheers,

Oliver

Comment: Confidence intervals make no sense any more after stepwise variable selection procedures (nor do p-values), unless you calculate them based on bootstrapping the entire procedure, including the stepping. There is an extensive literature on this, which I heartily recommend that you delve into. ORs may make sense, on the other hand (but you will be too sure of them after stepwise model building).

Comment: The stepwise procedure is just going to search out the 'best' model where 'best' is defined by some criteria. Once you have the final model why not just fit it explicitly (final.mod<-glm(y~covariatesFromStep, ....) and then use your typical methods for determining confidence intervals and other values of interest from the mode.

Comment: Dear Steve and Stephan. Thanks both of you for your comments. Yes, I've started reading about why stepward selection models aren't really recommended. Interesting stuff! The idea actually comes from the function in SPSS, where after a stepwise selection you are provided with these numbers. However, your points are so vaild. I prefer selecting via the AIC for model fit, as I find this more informative than dropping by p-values (as suggested by the F-test). @SteveReno that's a good idea. I'll do that! Thanks guys!